# Disable Transition if Scripts are disabled?

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

I created a transition in JavaScript which works like this:

```
document.getElementById("container").style.opacity = "1";
```

and in the CSS:

```
#container {
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity 2s;
}
```

But now I installed NoScript and the contents of the website didn't show, because the script couldn't run. 
Can I do anything against it?

Comment: Wow, you installed **NoScript** and wonder why Java**Script** no longer works?

Comment: No, I want to know if i can "check" if JavaScript is disabled...

Comment: Your'e getting down votes because your questing lacks any real investigation of your own, and also does not really explain the circumstances of your problem.  Of course, it's obvious that your `#container` won't show if you don't have Javascript enabled because that's what is showing your `#container` element, and so why does it have to either fade in or why do you not want Javascript?

Comment: You really didn't ask for that, but hey: [this is probably your solution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript).

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry for that. But still thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your content is not visible when JavaScript is disabled, then you should remove the `opacity: 0;` from your CSS, and let JavaScript initialize it, like this:

```
// we first hide the content using JS
// the content will be hidden *only and only if* JavaScript is enabled
document.getElementById('container').style.opacity = '0';

// we display the element after some delay or user interaction
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('container').style.opacity = '1';
}, 3000);
```

This is the best solution IMHO.

Alternatively, you can do something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        //...

        <style>
        .no-js #container {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        .js #container {
            opacity: 0;
            transition: opacity 2s;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body class="no-js">
        <div id="container">your content</div>
        //...
        <script>
            document.body.classList.remove('no-js');
            document.body.classList.add('js');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

You use a CSS `class` on `body` element which indicates whether JavaScript is enabled or not, and style your content accordingly.

This second technique is very powerfull, but be careful to not have too many `.no-js xxx` nor `.js xxx` CSS selectors as it may impact negatively the website rendering performance, reduce CSS lisibility and complicates it's maintainability.